# pyspark: rearrange nested array of struct sequence

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, schema

I've a dataframe in this format and I would like to rearrange the fields inside `item` column.

```
root
 |-- order: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dt: struct (nullable = true)
 |-- item: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- a: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- b: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- c: long (nullable = true)
```

So this is the desired format I'm looking for.

```
root
 |-- order: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dt: struct (nullable = true)
 |-- item: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- a: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- c: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- b: long (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `transform` function:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

result = df.withColumn(
    "item",
    F.expr("transform(item, x -> struct(x.a as a, x.c as c, x.b as b))")
)
```